# How do I convert an array of objects / subdocuments to an array of strings in a MongoDB Aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, mongodump

I have documents with the following structure

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"..."},
    "work_type": "ASSIGNMENT",
    
    "materials": [
        {
        "driveFile": {
            "driveFile": {
                "id": "...",
                "title": "filename",
                "alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/...",
                "thumbnailUrl": "https://drive.google.com/..."
            },
            "shareMode": "STUDENT_COPY"
        }
        },
        {
        "youtubeVideo": {
            "id": "tfdbq",
            "alternateLink": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=..."
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to convert the objects in the array to JSON strings so that I can import the materials field as a repeated string column in SQL

Resulting in:

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"..."},
    "work_type": "ASSIGNMENT",
    "materials": [
        "{\"driveFile\":{\"driveFile\":{\"id\":\"...\",\"title\":\"filename\",\"alternateLink\":\"https://drive.google.com/...\",\"thumbnailUrl\":\"https://drive.google.com/...\"},\"shareMode\":\"COPY"}}",
        "{\"youtubeVideo\":{\"id\":\"tfdbq\",\"alternateLink\":\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...\"}}""
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure is there any easy option do this, you can try [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator starting from MongoDB v4.4, indirectly it is JavaScript code,

- using `aggregate()`

```
  {
    $set: {
      materials: {
        $function: {
          body: function(materials) { 
            let m = []; 
            for (let i = 0; i < materials.length; i++) 
              m.push(JSON.stringify(materials[i])); 
            return m; 
          },
          args: ["$materials"],
          lang: "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aeSgjguR0Y0)

- using [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB v4.2

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1SXEaQtmutj)

Comment: Great idea - though Mongo Compass is claiming it's not a properly formatted document - I tried adding curly braces around the for loop contents and still it's not happy

Comment: i am not sure, can you test updating single document and look in any editor or mongo-compass, might be it will look weird in shell because of quotes and slash.

Comment: Sorry - it's not complaining about the resulting document, it's saying it can't parse the code provided, so it doesn't like what's in the body of the function for some reason

Comment: where you have tested this query? in compass's aggregation tab? try updating your mongodb compass version to latest. i have added playground link in answer it will help you,

Comment: Updated to shell 4.4.3, restarted compass, and tried to run agg in shell as well, still no luck

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {  materials: {$exists: true}}}, {$limit: 5}, {}, {    $set: {      materials: {        $function: {          body: function(materials) {             let m = [];             for (let i = 0; i < materials.length; i++)               {m.push(JSON.stringify(materials[i]));}             return m;           },          args: ["$materials"],          lang: "js"        }      }    }  }])

Comment: results in "errmsg" : "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field."

Comment: Ah body needs to be a string, I had a feeling that's what it was - trying that

Comment: the error is from blank stage `{}` after $limit stage, can you remove that and try again.

Comment: The lack of quotes was the issue, working now thanks!

Comment: So it works except now I'm getting "errmsg" : "Out of memory", "code" : 139,"codeName" : "JSInterpreterFailure" - I double checked and the max length of any of the arrays is 20, allowDiskUse doesn't seem to help, so might be stuck in the water on this one

Comment: don't do in full collection just limit the documents, this is just life saving option, this will take more execution because of executing other code.

Comment: Okay, this is actually an agg pipeline I wanted to run in order to do an export of a full collection, but will work on batching it up - thanks!

Comment: You can update using update with aggregation pipeline that i have added in second option and than export full collection.